# How to get row delta value by pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I got a dataframe combined by with `index = datetime` and `column = {'currentprice'}`

```
index               currentPrice
2015-03-26 10:09:01 75.75
2015-03-26 10:11:57 75.70
```

Now I want to get the delta value during every 3 minutes(as an example), the I can get a dataframe like this:

```
index               delta
2015-03-26 10:09:01 -0.05
2015-03-26 10:11:57 0.10
...
```

What should I do?

Comment: `df.diff().shift(-1)` works?

Comment: Thanks! I finally get this worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To expand upon the answer given in the comments, you can use

```
df['delta'] = df.currentPrice.diff().shift(-1)
```

to get the difference between the price in one row and the next. However if you're actually interested in finding the difference between time periods separated by 3 minutes, not the 2m56s in your data, you're going to need to resample your timeseries using the resample method as documented here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html